# Redux action.type gives @@redux/INIT

Tags: reactjs, redux

My reducer file is as follows.

```
import { AppConstants } from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  state: [],
  menu_items: [],
  addon_items: [],
  save_items: [],
  un_mapped_menu_items: false,
  error: ''
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
   case AppConstants.getMenuItems:
    return {
     ...state,
   }
   case AppConstants.getMenuItemsSuccess:
    return {
     ...state,
     menu_items: action.menu_items
    }
   case AppConstants.getAddonsItems:
    return {
     ...state,
   }
   case AppConstants.getAddonsItemsSuccess:
    return {
    ...state,
    addon_items: action.addon_items
   }
   case AppConstants.getMenuItemsEdit:
    return {
    ...state,
   }
   case AppConstants.getMenuItemsSave:
    return {
    ...state,
    save_items: action.save_items
   }
   case AppConstants.getUnmappedMenuItems:
    return {
    ...state,
    error: action.error,
    un_mapped_menu_items: true
   }
  case AppConstants.getMenuItemsError:
    return {
    ...state,
    error: action.error
   }
  default:
  return state
  }
 };
```

When I debug my reducer file the action.type shows '@@redux/INIT'. I do not understand this . why does this gives this? My action file gives correct data when debugging it. How do I remove this error?

Comment: How do you debug? At what time do you log the action type? By the way reducer doesn't generate actions thats why show the actions creators file instead.

Comment: Share the code from where you are actually getting the actions and AJAX call code if you are getting through AJAX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a store is created an `@@redux/INIT` action is dispatched  by `createStore`

From the Code:

```
export var ActionTypes = {
  INIT: '@@redux/INIT'
}

  // When a store is created, an "INIT" action is dispatched so that every
  // reducer returns their initial state. This effectively populates
  // the initial state tree.
  dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.INIT })
```

See the code here: 
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/v3.0.6/src/createStore.js